# How to call multiple functions with onPress, which has its own parameter in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, function

I am trying to call multiple functions when onPress is called in React Native. The problem is that where I call the functions, that function itself has a handlePress parameter. Here is the code:

```
const _renderTruncatedFooter = (handlePress) => {
      return (
        <Button
        accessoryLeft={MoreIcon}
        appearance='ghost'
        status='control'
        size = 'medium'
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={()=>{handlePress, storeRead(item), changeTitleColor();}} >
        {i18n.t('ShowMore')}
        </Button>
      );
  }
```

the other two functions, that I want to call are:

```
const storeRead = async (value) => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value)
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('read_data', jsonValue)
    alert('data saved')

  } catch (e) {
    alert('Failed to save the data to the storage')
  }
}
```

and the second one is:

```
const changeTitleColor = () => {
  setRead(true);
}
```

But this is not working. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

don't use comma inside your onPress props, just do like this

```
onPress={() => {
   handlePress();
   storeRead(item);
   changeTitleColor();
}}
```

Comment: It works! but why should I call a parameter as a function? I mean can we?

Comment: that's because your ```handlePress``` parameter is a function. 
if you want to call a single function you can use ```onPress={handlePress}``` ,
but it doesn't work if you want to call multiple function, you need to do like what i suggest above, because this is how it's works.

Comment: okay, my pleasure 

Answer (score 0):

call one function in on press like sectionOne

so in section one, you can call your all rest function

not call all functions in onPress